# compute matrix from list and two numbers that powers the elements

Tags: python, function, matrix

I'm trying to define a function. The function should compute a matrix from inserting a list of numbers and two additional numbers, which should be the range of what each element in the list is going to be powered to, in the command line.

For example if I insert `powers([2,3,4],0,2)` in the command line, the output should be a 3x3 matrix with the first row `[2^0,2^1,2^2]`, the second `[3^0,3^1,3^2]` and third row `[3^0,3^1,3^2]`.

It should look something like:

input: `powers([2,3,4],0,2)`

output: `[[1, 2, 4],[1,3,9],[1,4,16]]`

Does anyone know how to do something like that by not importing any additional package to python?

So far I have

```py
def powers(C,a,b):

    for c in C:
        matrix=[]

        for i in range(a,b):
            c = c**i
            matrix.append(c)
        
    print(matrix)
```

But that only gives me one row of ones.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your outer loop, you're emptying the matrix in each iteration. In your inner loop you're appending the powers directly to the matrix, when you should instead create a sub-list and append the numbers to it, then, append the sub-list to the matrix. All you need for this is a simple list comprehension:

```
def powers(C, a, b):
    matrix = [[c ** i for i in range(a, b + 1)] for c in C]
    return matrix
```

Test:

```
>>> powers([2, 3, 4], 0, 2)
[[1, 2, 4], [1, 3, 9], [1, 4, 16]]
```

The range is `range(a, b + 1)` because Python's range stops one step before the end (it doesn't include the end), so to include `b` use `b + 1`.